# Replace part of a 16 bit integer with an 8 bit integer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, integer

In this example, I have a struct composed of 16 bit integers. I read certain parts of those integers to the components of a struct of 8 bit integers. I then manipulate the 8 bit integers and I want to reload the 16 bit integers. The code below explains a little better. Any ideas?

```
    struct SIXTEEN
    {
      uint16_t COMPONENT[8];
    };

    struct EIGHT
    {
      uint8_t COMP1;
      uint8_t COMP2;
      uint8_t COMP3;
    };

    void main()
    {
      //For the purposes of this example, assume *S is a pointer to
      // this array                        
      // 0000 AABB CC00 0000
      struct SIXTEEN *S;

      struct EIGHT E;

      E.COMP1 = S -> COMPONENT[2]; //AA
      E.COMP2 = S -> COMPONENT[3]; //BB
      E.COMP3 = S -> COMPONENT[4]; //CC

      //Let's manipulate these a little
      struct EIGHT HOLD;
      HOLD.COMP1 = E.COMP3; //HOLD.COMP1 has CC
      E.COMP3 = E.COMP1; //E.COMP3 has AA
      E.COMP2 = HOLD.COMP1; //E.COMP2 has CC
      E.COMP1 = E.COMP2; //E.COMP1 has BB

      //Now I want to pass the components of E into their new 
      //places in S so the array in S becomes:
      // 0000 BBCC AA00 0000
      //
      // No idea, this certainly doesn't work:
      // S -> COMPONENT[2] = E.COMP1;
    }
```

This is one problem in a larger project so I'm not getting rid of pointer S.

Comment: "assume *S is a pointer to
      // this array                        
      // 0000 AABB CC00 0000" and `uint16_t COMPONENT[8];` lacks detail.  What should be assumed about the remaining 12 elements?  `S -> COMPONENT[2]; //AA` is unclear.  `S -> COMPONENT[2];` is `CC00` per the given assumption.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do what you want, and in both ways you must know the endianness of your CPU. Given that you have basically two structs:

> struct SIXTEEN { uint16_t COMPONENT[8]; };
>   struct EIGHT { uint8_t COMP1 COMP2 COMP3 };

You can use a `union` to create a type which is accessible in either ways, either by copying your source data in that union, or by using pointers and type casting. But I think that using pointers is more simple. With your data:

> struct SIXTEEN *S;   // points to "0000 AABB CC00 0000"
>      struct EIGHT E;

by doing

```
E.COMP1 = S -> COMPONENT[2]; //AA
```

you don't get AA, you get the 8 lower bits of the *third* element, i.e. CC or perhaps the 00 next to CC.

Try instead:

```
uint8_t* ptr;
ptr = (uint8_t *) & S -> COMPONENT[1];   // points to AABB
E.COMP1 = *(ptr +0);     // you get AA or BB
E.COMP2 = *(ptr +1);     // you get the other one
E.COMP3 = *(ptr +2);     // you get CC or 00
```

This way is easy to understand and easy to modify, just play with +0, +1 and so on. Once manipulation of E.COMPx is done, you can write data back in the same manner:

```
*(ptr +0) = E.COMP1;
```

You can also use the array notation []; using pointer arithmetic seems more self-explaining to me, but it's matter of taste and the final result is probably exactly the same.

Comment: There are compliant & portable ways.

Comment: @olaf yes... feel free to post an answer about them.

Comment: @Olaf: The Standard would only allow the `union` approach in situations where the objects either have no declared type or are declared as being that union type.  The Standard would allow implementations to behave in arbitrary fashion if a pointer of the union type were used to access an object whose declared type was, e.g. `uint16_t`.  The Standard would require implementations where type uint8_t *exists*, however, to allow code to manipulate octets within larger types using type `unsigned char*` (it does *not* mandate that they allow `uint8_t*` to be used for such purpose, though...

Comment: ...many implementations will do so anyway).  The Standard does not specify any means by which code wanting to access any other size chunk of a larger type (e.g. 16 bits from a 32-bit value) to do so, and compilers like gcc require that code either use non-standard syntax or options like `-fno-strict-aliasing`, or else use two 8-bit accesses and hope a compiler can figure out that it could use one 16-bit access instead.

Comment: @supercat: Did I write to use pointers or other code invoking UB? Both approaches (as much as one can get from the text) are not good - at best.

Comment: @Olaf: While you gloss over the concept of using a `union`, someone who understood the concept but didn't didn't know how gcc interprets the Standard might expect them to be more powerful than gcc's interpretation of the Standard requires them to be.  Also, while compilers that want to be suitable for processing certain kinds of existing code *should* treat `uint8_t` as a character type, nothing in the Standard requires that implementations do so.  If `uint8_t` exists, `unsigned char*` will be 8 bits, and is the only unsigned type which is guaranteed to be treated as a "character type"...

Comment: ...for aliasing purposes.

Comment: @supercat: You put a meaning into my comments which is not stated. Neither a `union` nor pointers are required. For the sake of dicussion: `uint8_t` cannot be different than `unsigned char` or `char` (if that is unsigned on the platform). **Iff it exists**.

Comment: @Olaf: The Standard allows implementations to define extended integer types of any size; e.g. a compiler for an 8-bit platform might define an "uint24_t" which takes 3 bytes and can perform computations 25% faster than a uint32_t.  Nothing would forbid an implementation from having CHAR_BITS==8 but having `uint8_t` be an alias for an 8-bit extended integer type rather than `unsigned char`, nor from making such a type be alias-compatible only with itself.  Doing so could improve performance of code which works anyway.

Comment: @supercat: I did not mention any other type than `uint8_t` for good reason. Think about it!

Comment: @Olaf: Implementations commonly implement `uint8_t` as an alias for `unsigned char`, but nothing in the Standard would forbid an implementation from defining it as some other type which had the same size and representation but was not alias-compatible with it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to overwrite one half of a 16 bit int with an 8 bit value.  You can do this:

```
uint16_t big = 0xBEEF;

big = (big & 0xFF00) | 0x42;
assert(big == 0xBE42);

big = (big & 0x00FF) | 0x86 << 8;
assert(big == 0x8642);
```

Which using your variable names is:

```
S->COMPONENT[2] = (S->COMPONENT[2] & 0xFF00) | E.COMP1;
```

or

```
S->COMPONENT[2] = (S->COMPONENT[2] & 0x00FF) | E.COMP1 << 8;
```

depending on whether you want to replace the first or second byte.

Comment: Can you explain this in context of the question?

Comment: @CraigK.: "Replace part of a 16 bit integer with an 8 bit integer"

Comment: Yes but could you use the variables in the example. Would it be something like uint16_t big = S -> COMPONENT[2], big = (big & 0xFF00) | E.COMP1; assert(true);

Comment: On typical 8 or 16 bit systems the code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf, can you explain why?

Comment: @CraigK.: I have updated my answer using your specific variable names instead.  It should be usable code now, though you need to choose which half of the target you're trying to overwrite.

Comment: @KeineLust bitshift signed integers.